# Different result when calling Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand why test3 and test1 produce the same result, which is an array [1,2] but test2 produces an empty array. Isn't the Function property arguments returning an array like object? I expect all three test results to produce an array of [1,2].

```js
/*eslint-disable no-console */
var testFunc = function(){
    console.log(arguments);
    console.log("test3: ", Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));
};

testFunc(1,2);
console.log("test1: ", Array.prototype.slice.apply([1,2]));
console.log("test2: ", Array.prototype.slice.apply({[0]:1, [1]:2}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test2` doesn't produce the result you expect because you're calling it on a non-array-like object: it's missing `length`. `test1` and `test3` produce the result you expect because you're calling it on array-like objects. Since `test2` is missing length, when `slice` reads `length`, it gets `undefined`, which gets converted to `NaN`, so `0` gets used as the length of the source array. (If you're curious, in the spec it's [`slice`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.slice) -> [LengthOfArrayLike(obj)](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-lengthofarraylike) -> [ToLength(obj.length)](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tolength) -> [ToInteger(undefined)](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tointeger) -> [ToNumber(undefined)](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumber); ToNumber returns `NaN`, which ToInteger converts to `0`.)

If we add `length` to `test2`, it also produces what you expect:

```js
/*eslint-disable no-console */
var testFunc = function(){
    console.log(arguments);
    console.log("test3: ", Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));
};

testFunc(1,2);
console.log("test1: ", Array.prototype.slice.apply([1,2]));
console.log("test2: ", Array.prototype.slice.apply({0:1, 1:2, length:2}));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

Side note: No need for computed property notation when building the array-like object for `test2`, numeric literals are valid property names in object literals (I've removed the computed notation in the snippet above).

Answer (score 1):

For an object to be array-like, it needs to have a `.length` property:

```js
console.log("test2: ", Array.prototype.slice.apply({0:1, 1:2, length: 2}));
```